# スコア5000で付与されるサイトのアナリティクス閲覧権限についての説明が英語のまま

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

[image: 権限リスト]

ここにあるにある現在スコア５０００の最高スコアで獲得できる権限名が英語のままになっています
この権現をクリックしたリンク先も同じくほとんど英語の説明のままになっています

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

[image: 権限の内容（英語）]

あまり必要性はないかもしれませんが
とつぜんの英語にびっくりしたので改善お願いしたいです

Answer (score 2):

[権限名と概要文はTransifex上で翻訳済み](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/60112314?comment=25k%20user%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E8%A7%A3%E6%9E%90%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)なのですが、サイトに適用されていないようです。

ヘルプの本文についてはTransifexやモデレーター権限でも直接は編集できないので、一旦ここに草案を書いた上で反映してもらおうと思います。誤訳や文章に違和感があればコメントしていただくか、コミュニティWikiにしてあるので直接編集してください。

---

### アクセス解析とは？

サイトにどのような人が訪れ、どのように使われているかといった情報です。普通はサイトの運営者がこの情報をサイト運営に生かしますが、このサイトは[コミュニティによって運営されています](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/)から、積極的に参加しているユーザーにこの情報を開放しています。

この権限を獲得すると、[/site-analytics](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics)で以下の二つのタブを見ることができます。

#### 履歴

3つのグラフはそれぞれ投稿数、投票数、アクセス数を表しています。ページ上部にあるテキストボックスで、集計対象となる日付範囲を指定することができます。

[image: Timeline controls]

その下にはサイトの節目となる日付が表示されていて、これをクリックすると集計開始日がその日付になります。Weeklyにチェックを入れると週単位の数値になります。

データの系列はグラフ左側にあるチェックボックスで表示を切り替えることができます。

[image: Data series toggle]

また、手元で解析を行えるようにCSV形式でのダウンロードもできます。なお、SEDEなどと異なり、このデータは削除済みの投稿も含んだ数値です。

#### Google Analytics

このタブでは過去30日間の [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) の情報にアクセスすることができます。ただし、

- DuckDuckGoは検索エンジンではなく[リンク元サイトとして](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics)表示されます
- それぞれの数値は[統計処理された値](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/analytics-search-keywords-are-unreliable)なので、ある検索エンジンからの流入がきっかり211回だった、という正確な情報を示すものではありません
- APIの呼び出し回数に制限があるため、任意の集計範囲を指定することはできません
- 検索キーワードの情報はあてにならないので表示していません

### これをどう使うべきでしょうか？

まずこれは一部ユーザーに与えられた特権ですから、生データを公開するのは避け、あなたが分析した結果をメタサイトで共有するようにしてください。例えば成熟したStackExchangeサイトは検索エンジンからの流入が多くなる傾向にあります。そのような流入がどのくらいの割合を占めているかを見ることは、そのサイトの現状を把握するのに役立ちます。

これらの分析や共有は義務ではありません。権限を持っている人に情報の開示を強いることも避けるべきです。あくまであなた自身の興味や関心を満たすための機能とお考えください。

Comment: とりあえずこのままに適用しました：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics　更新が必要なら、ご教示ください。